# Métodos similares a onPause() y onResume() en un Dialogo

Tags: android

Me gustaría saber que métodos son similares a `onPause()` y `onResume()` pero en una clase que extiende de Dialog.

Lo quiero saber para registrar un broadcastReciver `registerReceiver(broadcast)` y para desregistrarlo `unregisterReceiver(broadcast)`. En una actividad normal lo haría sobreescribiendo los metodos `onPause()` y `onResume()` pero en un dialogo no se exactamente donde sería correcto hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo en la documentación oficial la clase Dialog posee los métodos "onStart" y "onStop" además del "onCreate" https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html

Cualquiera de ellos debería servirte

Answer (score 0):

En un [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) no existen los métodos `onPause()` y `onResume()` estos son manejados por la Activity que crea el Dialogo.

> Un  **[Dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)**  únicamente podría manejar [onStart()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#onStart()) (Cuando
>   inicia el Dialogo) y [onStop()](http://onStop()) (Cuando se detiene la actividad que
>   lo crea).
>
> Un **[DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)** es similar contiene los métodos [onStart()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onStart())
>   (Se llama cuando el DialogFragment es visible) y [onStop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onStop()) (Se
>   llama cuando el DialogFragment no ha iniciado).

**En ambos casos los métodos  `onPause()` y `onResume()` si es que los deseas utilizar, serían los propios de la `Activity` que crea el `Dialog` o `DialogFragment`.**